# CUDNN rnn error - Failed to call ThenRnnForward

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gpu, recurrent-neural-network, cudnn

- OS Platform and Distribution - Ubuntu 16.04
- TensorFlow installed from TensorFlow version 1.4 with Bazel Version 0.6.1
- CUDA Version 9.0.176
- Machine Type -n1-standard-32 (32 vCPUs, 120 GB memory) GPU - 4 x NVIDIA Tesla P100

I am using a `cudnnrnnrelu` like this :

```python
with tf.variable_scope('cudnn_rnn_stack', reuse = reuse) as scope:
    rnn = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnRNNRelu(5,n_hidden,"linear_input", "bidirectional")
    output, _ = rnn(tf.transpose(layer_1,[1,0,2]), training=True)
    output_rnn_stack = tf.concat(output, 2)
```

Running it on a distributed gpu setting in gcp instances, the epochs were initially running fine. But I encountered this error after 2-3 epochs:

```
InternalError (see above for traceback): Failed to call ThenRnnForward
[[Node: tower_0/cudnn_rnn_stack/cudnn_rnn_relu/CudnnRNN =
CudnnRNN[T=DT_FLOAT, direc tion="bidirectional", dropout=0,
input_mode="linear_input", is_training=true, rnn_mode="rnn_r elu",
seed=0, seed2=0,
device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](tower_0/cudnn
rnn_stack/transpose, tower_0/cudnn_rnn_stack/cudnn_rnn_relu/zeros,
tower_0/cudnn_rnn_stack/cu dnn_rnn_relu/Const,
cudnn_rnn_stack/cudnn_rnn_relu/opaque_kernel/read)]] [[Node:
Adam/update_cudnn_rnn_stack/cudnn_rnn_relu/opaque_kernel/ApplyAdam/_870
= _R ecvclient_terminated=false, cv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_nam
e="edge_2200_Adam/update_cudnn_rnn_stack/cudnn_rnn_relu/opaque_kernel/ApplyAdam",
tensor_type
=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
```

Comment: I would like you to give more information: You are running it locally or do you use ML Engine? Could you put the command that you are running and the configuration that you use? Could you put a more complete code to give me a better idea of ​​what is happening?

Comment: Not sure if this is very helpful, but i ran into that message when I had 'too many' RNNs in the same model (since it was multiple dimensional) and so I had 3 blocks of 8 RNNs, reducing it to two blocks of 8 fixed the issue.

Comment: I hit the same error running the same script twice on the same host